# Facebook Event Cover URL

Tags: javascript, facebook, events, graph

For days i was creating events by JS API and everything was ok. Two days from now Im getting a...

```
code: 2
message: "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later."
type: "OAuthException"
```

... everytime I try to update the cover_url of the created event. My code is just:

```
FB.api(
eventId,'post',
{ cover_url:'<url>'}, function...
```

I have already tryed everything that I found in documentation.

Look at the new documentation and didn't find anything.

Comment: did you found any solution already?
It used to work for me, but now it corrupted

Answer (score 0):

Solve the problem:

Just change 'event_privacy' to 'OPEN' when creating. After this, event cover_url update works fine.

Hope it helps.

Comment: does this still work for you? My covers stopped uploading some time in december and this does not seem to fix the problem.

Comment: The response here solved my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20968323/uploading-a-cover-to-an-event-through-the-facebook-api-throws-an-exception/21186982#21186982