# Uploading a cover to an event through the facebook api throws an Exception

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, curl

I used to be able to upload cover photos to facebook events through http posts using the method described in this post: [Facebook PHP SDK: Upload Event Cover Photo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725574/facebook-php-sdk-upload-event-cover-photo)

It stopped working recently, the event is created but the cover won't upload anymore, with the graph giving the following response at my attempts:

`"{"error":{"type":"Exception","message":"The user doesn't have permission to attach this photo to another object.","code":1366035}}"`

The facebook documentation is scarce when it comes to handling cover images and I can't find any mention of this specific error code.

Has anyone come by this issue before?

Comment: Are you able to upload the cover to an event? If yes, can you please show

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue using user_token to add event and cover into page.
My workaround is to get page_token using that user_token, and then create event and cover using page_token.

```
$fb->setAccessToken($user_token); //set your user token

$result = $fb->api($page_id.'?fields=access_token', 'get');

if(isset($result["access_token"])) //this will be set if your user has a permission on the page.
{
    $page_token = $result["access_token"]; 
    $fb->setAccessToken($page_token); 
}

//create event add cover as before
```

Comment: Well facebook wasn't able to give me a conclusive answer on this and here you are, walking through my dungeon door with this piece. My hero. Here is my Stackoverflow approval, good sir.